# Is there a way to write data to excel file without losing formatting

Tags: excel, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have a prefilled excel file in the assets folder and I need to write some data collected within the app to this file and give it to user.

I'm using the excel.dart package and can successfully read the excel file, perform my actions and save it. However, when I try to open the excel file, Im getting this error:

[image: excel error]

If I click yes and view the repaired file, then a few more errors are shown:

[image: error 1]

[image: error 2]

here's the relevant part of the code:

```dart
writeToExcel() async {
    final outputFile = File(_outputFilePath);
    
    // Load the Excel file
    var bytes = File(_excelFilePath).readAsBytesSync();
    var wb = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);

    final detailsMapping = _cellMappings.detailsMapping;
    final componentsMapping = _cellMappings.componentsMapping;
    var sheet = wb["IA"];

    // ... writing data to sheet

    final excelOutput = wb.save();
    await outputFile.writeAsBytes(excelOutput!);
  }
```